# Adding a description box to a quiz using action script 3

Tags: actionscript-3

Basically im trying to add a description box to a quiz which I've created using actionscript 3. When users complete the quiz if they select a wrong answer a cross appears next to that specific question. It would be nice to have a description box appear to explain why that question is wrong and the what the correct answer is when they select an answer. However I am having difficulty implementing this.

I would really appreciate some help with this thankyou in advance. My code below:-

```
var qno=0;
var rnd1; 
var rnd2;
tick.visible=false;
cross.visible=false;
var right_answers=0;
var wrong_answers=0;

/////////////////////////////////options don't match questionz

function change_question(){
    if(tick.visible){right_answers++;}
    if(cross.visible){wrong_answers++;}


    if(qno==questions.length){gotoAndPlay(2);}else{
    tick.visible=false;cross.visible=false;
    rnd1=Math.ceil(Math.random()*3);
    rnd2=Math.ceil(Math.random()*questions.length)-1;
    q.text=questions[rnd2];
    if(questions[rnd2]=="x"){

        change_question();


        }
    questions[rnd2]="x";
    enable_disable(1);
    if(rnd1==1){opt1.text=answers[rnd2][0];opt2.text=answers[rnd2][1];opt3.text=answers[rnd2][2];}
    if(rnd1==2){opt1.text=answers[rnd2][2];opt2.text=answers[rnd2][0];opt3.text=answers[rnd2][1];}
    if(rnd1==3){opt1.text=answers[rnd2][1];opt2.text=answers[rnd2][2];opt3.text=answers[rnd2][0];}
    }}

function enable_disable(a){
    if(a==0){shade1.mouseEnabled=false;shade2.mouseEnabled=false;shade3.mouseEnabled=false;}
    if(a==1){shade1.mouseEnabled=true;shade2.mouseEnabled=true;shade3.mouseEnabled=true;}}

change_question();

NextBTN.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ButtonAction1);
function ButtonAction1(eventObject:MouseEvent) {qno++;change_question();} 

shade1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ButtonAction2);
shade2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ButtonAction3);
shade3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ButtonAction4);

function ButtonAction2(eventObject:MouseEvent) {enable_disable(0);if(rnd1==1){tick.visible=true;tick.y=shade1.y}else{cross.visible=true;cross.y=shade1.y}}
function ButtonAction3(eventObject:MouseEvent) {enable_disable(0);if(rnd1==2){tick.visible=true;tick.y=shade2.y}else{cross.visible=true;cross.y=shade2.y}}
function ButtonAction4(eventObject:MouseEvent) {enable_disable(0);if(rnd1==3){tick.visible=true;tick.y=shade3.y}else{cross.visible=true;cross.y=shade3.y}}




stop();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit opaque, but why not just create your 'correct-answer' explanations as graphic-and-text Sprites (e.g. the answer-text inside of a 'thought bubble' or box). Put 'em their proper places on stage but leave their 'visible' property set to 'false.' Let the wrong-answer 'x' be a Sprite as well. Target each particular 'x' instance with a listener function that changes the appropriate answer visible to 'true.'

Is it harder than that?